# What is the optimal SVN repository lay-out for multi-sourced projects?

Tags: svn

[note: I moved this from serverfault, as stackoverflow is probably more appropriate]

For a project we are working on we are developing a WordPress theme, some WordPress custom plugin, an iOS application and an Android application. We handle all source code via an internal Subversion server, where each project has its own repository.

My question is: what is the optimal lay-out for the SVN repository for this project? Can I fit it in 1 repository, or should I really create separate repositories for the theme, the plugins and the mobile apps?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not whether separate repositories, but whether they should be managed as separate projects or not, which translates to whether they will be branched and merged together. In Subversion you can have multiple projects in one repository, so you can always have just one repository there.

The answer depends on how closely the modules will be tied together. If you expect any version of one component to work with, within reason, any other version of the other components, than they should be managed as separate projects (each with it's own `trunk` and `branches`, so you'd have `theme/trunk` and `theme/branches` and `plugin/trunk` etc.). If you expect that modifications will commonly touch more than one component, they have to be managed as single project (one `trunk` and `branches`, so you will have `trunk/theme` and `trunk/plugin` etc.).

On a side-note, I'd suggest reconsidering the choice of subversion. The newer distributed systems (in order of popularity [Git](http://git-scm.org), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/)) offer more flexibility and superior branching and merging. The subversion implementation still shows rough edges after those years, in major part because the underlying model is not very good fit for branching.

Unlike subversion, distributed systems always have one project per repository, because branches are separate concept there, so you would have separate repositories (on one server anyway) if you decide to have separate projects.

Comment: Thank you Jan. We are currently using the second lay-out you recommend, which makes the most sense according to your explanation: when we change something in the plugins, we often also update the theme and the mobile apps. I'm glad to hear this is the correct way to handle this.

I also understand your point about distributed systems. We've been using SVN for quite some time now and there's never been a good reason to switch yet. But I am open to switching when the need arises.

Comment: @vvanscherpenseel: I've never encountered a point where I had to flee from subversion either. It's instead little nuisances with subversion mishandling something from time to time or not having some feature that would save you a bit of work here or there.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just create a single project with separate branches?

Comment: Yes, that's an idea, but how can I do release branching for the separate projects? Like a 1.0 release for the WordPress theme and a 1.1 release for the iOS source?

Comment: -1: Branches are appropriate for things, that are expected to be merged together. That and only that. That's nowhere even remotely this case.